# Search Windows share from OS X

Tags: windows, macos, mac, network-shares

Is there a way to search the file contents of a windows share in OS X (specifically Lion)?

i.e. Find all files in a shared directory Foo containing the words "Bar".

Comment: I take it you're finding opening a finder window on a shared folder and using the spotlight search box (upper right of the finder window) doesn't do the trick?

Comment: Correct.  The spotlight search box does not show any matches for a string I know exist in a file in the directory.